# Pass object into data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a data attribute like so:

```
<div data-id="">
```

In my markdown file I have frontmatter variable like so:

```
id: rick
```

Now I want to pass that object into `data-id` which only lets me add string.
How to make like so:

```
<div data-id="id"> or <div data-id={{ id }}> or <div :data-id={{ id }}>
```

I use vuejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind attributes to an element (or component) you use

```
<div :data-id="id">
   ...
</div>
```

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        id: 123
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div :data-id="id">
    This is rendered as div with and data-id="123"
  </div>
</div>
```